# Changes not implemented in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a very strange situation where changes I make to my project in eclipse, such as changing the text on a textview, is not shown in the emulator?

Has anyone has any hint as to what could be happening?

Escalating from the above, now I can't run the app at all after several 'clean ups'.

Now I've tried relaunching eclipse juno .. and on launching, the console (not the log cat says, in bright red)

```
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo] Versions found are:
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo] Path: C:\Users\User\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo]     Length: 648327
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo]     SHA-1: ded9acc6a9792b8f1afc470f0c9cd36d178914cd
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo] Path: C:\Users\User\workspace\admo\libs\android-support-v4.jar
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo]     Length: 758727
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo]     SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
   [2014-10-02 15:50:30 - admo] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

hmm.. whats happening?

In addition to the above, now by right clicking on the package in the package explorer and clicking run as> android application .. it says, 'android libraries cannot be launched' .. as mentioned below, libraries cannot be launched I know. But since when did my app suddenly became a 'library'?

Comment: try to Clean the project and run..

Comment: clean your project and build again ....

Comment: what does your logcat says when u fire an event

Comment: Right click on project > Source > Clean up?

Comment: yup that will solve ur prblem

Comment: Kinda made it worse. Now, on right clicking the project folder and 'run as android application', a pop up come up that says Android library projects cannot be launched?

Comment: @user65163 Dude. You are trying to library project,which can not be run. Library projects are always used by other projects it never runs.

Comment: OMG library project can not run directly for run them use in your application

Comment: I understand. But this should not be the case. I right click on my app folder on the right, go to 'run as> android application'. thats how I usually launch the app without problems..

Comment: Have you used library project in your project? Please do post some screenshots and make clear view of your problem so that one can provide proper solution.

Comment: Just to clarify, the 'android library projects cannot be launch' prompt is not showing now. Its just the logcat saying 'Could not find Test App.apk!

Comment: I'm using sqliteassethelper and google play services library, there's also android support v4.jar  in the android private libraries folder

Comment: try restarting ecllipse

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned above, I just did. Twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to clean your Project from Eclipse Menu Go to `Project>Clean..`  **OR** Right click on `Project>Source>CleanUp`

In eclipse it happens sometimes that it always refers to the old values. And doesn't shows you new defined values. So make sure you always clean your project in this situation.

Comment: I did the first one, Project>Clean .. says in the logcat 'Could not find Test App.apk!

Answer (score 1):

*Clean your project from Project -> Clean*

Comment: Took a turn for the worse . it could not launch now and in the log cat, it says [2014-10-02 15:32:51 - Test App] Could not find Test App.apk!

Comment: delete you bin folder from project and run again.

Comment: Try to rebuild your project From same Project menu and >Build Automatically.

Comment: in the 'project' tab on top, the 'build automatically' is ticked. in log cat, now it says Could not find Test App.apk!'

Comment: Lazy Coder .. delete the entire bin folder?

Comment: @LazyCoder He is trying to run library project. Which can not be run. Try to understand. He is worth trying.

Comment: @GrIsHu OMG but still last comment he never say this so we will giving solutions possible from us

Comment: @LazyCoder I already told him. Its not possible to run library project.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for trying to walk me through it. I found the problem, its probably my mistake, as the 'is library' checkbox is checked (tho I am pretty sure I didn't deliberately check it) in the android> properties.

Now unchecked, it ran ok.

As you all have suggested, since the clean up, the changes I make in xml and in the activities are now shown in the emulator.

The error with the libraries on the console, I'm not sure, but it came on after I created a new app. Deleted it and the problem disappeared. Anyway, will cross that bridge when I come to that.